# Disappearance of git repositories in Visual Studio 12

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using Visual Studio (12) with Test Complete for a few years and had several cloned git repositories.  I was using the Visual Studio GUI to connect, commit and pull.  I would access it by doing a "TEAM -> Connect to Team Foundation Server" and I could choose from the clones repositories.  Today when I do it there is none there (see image):

[image: Team Connect to Team Foundation Server]

I did some Googling and talked to a coworker who does the same thing.  He told me under Tools->options->source control to add "Microsoft GIT Provider" which must have been what I had had.  So I went to the menu (see below).  "Microsoft GIT Provider" is there and I can click but it doesn't change in the menu (I can't actually select it though it is there).  See picture below (and I apologize for the writing but Snipping Tool does not have Text Input):

[image]

I did get a git bash window and go to the directory and was able to do a "git status" which means the repositories are actually still there so it must be a VS issue.  I have Visual Studio Professional 2012, version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL.  Several items are listed.  The ones with Visual Studio are "Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker" and "Visual Studio 2012 Share Point Developer Tools" and "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012"

Any idea what may have happened?  GIT provider got uninstalled somehow or what?  I am not sure.  I guess I could do things from the command line.  Push and Pull are straightforward but some others are more complicated and it is much simpler to do from GUI.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why are you running such an old (and unsupported) version of Visual Studio?

Comment: As it is the only version that supports the C# code.  VS had a sea (sharp) change where it no longer recognizes statements such as triangle["side"](5);

Comment: I used to work on Visual Studio 2012 through 2017 when I was at Microsoft and that sounds like you had a broken local config - I can assure you there are no breaking-changes in any version of the C# language nor IDE and compiler where `triangle["side"](5);` would be invalid-syntax (I assume `triangle` is an object with an indexer-property that returns a delegate? Or is a `Dictionary<String,Action<Int32>>`?)

Comment: We had VS 15 and loaded our old legacy code and every line of code of that format was marked as a syntax error.  I think it wanted triangle.side(15) now, no?

Comment: There could be 1,000+ reasons for that... (and VS2015 is old now too anyway). Better idea: fire-up a new VM and install something recent like VS2022 or VS2019 (Community Edition is free-as-in-beer, don't forget) using stock/default options and see what happens. I'll be very surprised if you have any issues.

Comment: @Tony without seeing the exact definitions in play, we can't comment on what the code *should* be - however: there haven't been any changes to the language *of that nature* - the bar for breaking language changes has always been **very** high (as in: virtually never); I suspect you're mis-interpreting a failure scenario - my guess would be a problem resolving dependencies. The only even mildly valid reason for running such an old IDE would be something like "we're targeting some obscure compact-framework (or whatever) platform that was deprecated 9 years ago"

Comment: I will have to ask corporate whether we can do that, but I will and get back to you.  Thanks for the idea.  Not sure how long it will take for them to approve and do it but I will try.

Comment: It may be the Test Complete (Connect) code that it didn't like.

Comment: @Tony ...you need to ask permission _to use the tools needed to do your job_? I might suggest switching employers..

Comment: Sorry I cannot get the formatting better:
value = resultGrid["wValue"](row, column)["ToString"]()["OleValue"];
                
                value = resultGrid["wValue"](row, column)["ToString"]()["OleValue"];
                sqlResultsInUI.Add(value);
                

-- Cannot implicitly convert type 'AutomatedQA.script.var.VarDelegate' to string